# Angular Router button not triggering submit event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

The problem I'm facing is that the **button is not triggering the submit event** in this code, but if I **remove the router link, then it starts triggering the event** like it should normally. I am guessing that routing takes place before the event can be triggered.

How can I change my code so that it *runs the onSubmit() function and then starts routing*.

I have a simple angular code:

HTML

```
<form (submit)="onSubmit(theForm)" #homeForm='ngForm' ngControl="homeForm">
  <button 
    mat-raised-button
    color="accent"
    routerLink="/form"
    routerLinkActive="active">
    Submit
  </button>
  <mat-card>
      <mat-checkbox>Check me!</mat-checkbox>
  </mat-card>
</form>
```

TYPESCRIPT

```
import { Component, Output, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, FormGroup,  NgForm, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log('You submit to me?');
    console.log(form);

  }
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually `route` in your `onSubmit` handler

Make the following changes

**.ts**

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private router : Router) { }

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log('You submit to me?');
    console.log(form);
    this.router.navigate(['/forms']);

  }
```

Also remove your `routerLink` from **.html**

Comment: also import router in your **ts**, `import { Router } from '@angular/route'`